# Can I Navigate back to my application upon reaching a destination using Device.OpenUri?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, maps, open-uri

I have done some research for xamarin.forms to see what is the best way to navigate to a driving destination (longitude, Latitude) with excellent user controls. It seems there is no point in re-inventing the wheel, especially when its as complicated as googles fantastic maps solution.. So it seems there are two legal and simple ways: a embedded browser control / webview, or using Device.OpenUri.

So, Device.OpenUri is the most responsive, and easy way to get someone to a destination but how can I return the user to my app after they reach their destination? I would prefer not to rely upon them pressing the 'back' button to exit maps as this might be not intuitive to the user.

What do you think?

EDIT: ok so I realized my question is not maps related at all, because its not hard to track the phones GPS location. All I need to accomplish this, is: to re-activate (or 'Show') my app. So after I call Device.OpenUri, I think my app will still be running, so regardless of what program is currently 'on top' or active, what code can I run to bring back the current app? Or, would this need to be a 'notification' which would then allow the user to manually switch back?

Comment: Well how can i put this the right way, Its Impossible using Device.OpenUri

Comment: I dont think the Device.OpenUri method would able to implement your requirements